# Éviter la répétition de l'article ou d'un adjectif possessif

Tags: articles

Lorsque j'écris une liste de noms (dont le premier élément serait introduit par un article ou un adjectif possessif) en prose française, j'hésite à répéter ce même participe avant chaque mot, de peur de trop allonger la liste ou de la rendre peu naturelle.

J'aimerais savoir si la répétition est simplement acceptable  en français ou sinon y a-t-il des astuces pour la éviter?

Par exemple, je voudrais décrire le rôle d'un membre à bord d'un avion militaire:

*Il veille sur son chargement, son déchargement (et parfois son largage), son arrimage et son bon centrage sur l'aéronef.*

Serait-il acceptable d'entreprendre l'opération suivante: *son* x 5 = *ses*

*Il veille sur ses chargement, déchargement (et parfois largage), arrimage et bon centrage sur l'aéronef.*

Answer (score 1):

Il est aussi correct de dire "Il veille sur son chargement, déchargement, (parfois largage), arrimage et bon centrage sur l'aéronef".

Comment: D'accord, mais s'il on ajoute *manutention* à cette liste, c'est foutu!

Comment: @Hautfrançais Pourquoi l'ajouter ? Il semble que l'on parle du travail d'un manutentionnaire, et la manutention consiste, dans le cas présent, à exécuter les procédures mentionnées.

Comment: Si on ajoute manutention, ce n'est pas f***u, c'est différent. Je réponds simplement à la question, telle qu’énoncée.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'est pas d'usage de personnaliser son outil de travail dans les procédures techniques, ni de s'approprier les outils ou objets qui appartiennent en fait à autrui, le plus usité :

> Il veille sur le chargement, le déchargement (et parfois le largage), l'arrimage et le bon centrage de l'aéronef [induit : celui dont il ou elle a la responsabilité].

Il veille sur le chargement, le déchargement (et parfois le largage), l'arrimage et le bon centrage de *son* aéronef, pourra être dit lors d'un cours ou pour une explication orale.

Habituellement, à l'écrit, on met l'article devant chaque phase citée de la manœuvre pour insister sur la nécessité de l'exécuter correctement ; on le met moins à l'oral lorsqu'on rappelle seulement la liste des tâches à accomplir.

En reconstruisant la phrase sans article :

> Chargement, déchargement (et parfois largage), arrimage et centrage de l'aéronef sont surveillés par [il] (le chargeur, le manutentionnaire, le responsable du fret ....)

Il n'y a pas de faute réelle à utiliser *son* et de le répéter à chaque fois.

En revanche utiliser *ses* n'est pas une faute mais sonne mal à l'oreille, cela va perturber l'écoute ; à l'écrit on peut présenter différemment en utilisant *les*:

> Il veille sur *les*
>
> - chargement,
> - déchargement (et parfois largage),
> - arrimage
> - et bon centrage
>
> de l'aéronef.

Comment: Pardon, *son* renvoie à une cargaison quelconque.

Comment: J'ai complété l'introduction, la cargaison n'appartient pas à celle ou celui qui formule la phrase

Comment: Where you've replaced the 5 "son"s with "le", could all but the first new "le" be omitted? (i.e., "Il veille sur le chargement, déchargement (et parfois largage), arrimage et bon centrage de l'aéronef" and "Il veille sur le chargement, déchargement (et parfois largage), arrimage et bon centrage de son aéronef" ? (I understand/agree that putting the plural (sons or les) just once at the beginning in front of a singular noun would sound funny in sentence form, but it's not clear (to me) if the article "le" can be omitted after its first appearance at the beginning of the list in sentence form.)

Comment: @PapaPoule Instinctivement j'utilise *les* à la place du premier *le* et je supprime les autres *lel* comme sur le dernier exemple - Pour prendre en compte votre commentaire, j'ai ajouté une reformulation de la phrase sans article ni pronom.